# Retracted Spam flags should not reflect the Moderator action on the post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flags, retracted-flags

I recently saw a [borderline spam answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39575093/2415822) from SmokeDetector and quickly flagged it as spam. Upon further reflection, I wasn't sure if this was actual spam or a new user with a bad answer. I retracted the Spam flag and re-flagged as not an answer.

After the flag was handled by Undo, the Spam flag is listed as "disputed" instead of "self-removed" in my flagging history. Is this a bug due to a race condition? If the Spam flag wasn't retracted properly before the Undo handled the flag, wouldn't I have not been able to flag the answer as NAA? Moderation action isn't shown on other posts in my flag history for retracted flags.

[image: Post in Question]

[image: Flag History]

Comment: In retrospect, you probably retracted your flag *before* I marked everything disputed there. The disputing probably doesn't look at flag state, it just disputes all the spam flags.

Comment: Exact same question on meta.SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334780/retracted-flag-was-changed-to-disputed/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [animuson's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334787/2415822) on an identical Meta Stack Overflow post linked by Ashish Ahuja:

> This can only ever happen with spam/offensive flags. When a moderator uses the "clear all spam/offensive flags" tool on a post, it simply changes all spam/offensive flags (both handled and pending) on the post to disputed, regardless of what status they previously had.

I am assuming this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: It's "by-design" insofar as the logic is working as designed; whether that design is appropriate is a longer discussion, but currently this is so rare as to hardly be worth that discussion.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this and adding the mod tag, Shog.